# numpy: efficiently obtain a statistic over array elements grouped by the elements of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Apologies in advance for the potentially misleading title. I could not think of the way to properly word the problem without an illustrative example.

I have some data array (e.g.):

```
 x = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3])
```

and a corresponding array of equal length which indicates which elements of `x` are grouped:

```
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1])
```

In this example, there are two groupings in `x`: `[2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]` where `y=0`; and `[1,1,2,2,3,3]` where `y=1`. I want to obtain a statistic on all elements of `x` where `y` is 0, then 1. I would like this to be extendable to large arrays with many groupings. `y` is always ordered from lowest to highest **AND** is always sequentially increasing without any missing integers between the min and max. For example, `y` could be `np.array([0,0,**1**,2,2,2,2,3,3,3])` for some `x` array of the same length but not `y = np.array([0,0,**2**,2,2,2,2,3,3,3])` as this has no ones.

I can do this by brute force quite easily for this example.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3])
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1])

y_max = np.max(y)
stat_min = np.zeros(y_max+1)
stat_sum = np.zeros(y_max+1)

for i in np.arange(y_max+1):
    stat_min[i] = np.min(x[y==i])
    stat_sum[i] = np.sum(x[y==i])

print(stat_min)
print(stat_sum)
```

Gives: `[2. 1.]` and `[27. 12.]` for the minimum and sum statistics for each grouping, respectively. I need a way to make this efficient for large numbers of groupings and where the arrays are very large (> 1 million elements).

**EDIT**

A bit better with list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3])
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1])

y_max = np.max(y)

stat_min = np.array([np.min(x[y==i]) for i in range(y_max+1)])
stat_sum = np.array([np.sum(x[y==i]) for i in range(y_max+1)])

print(stat_min)
print(stat_sum)
```

Comment: Do you insist on using numpy? Because this is a relatively easy thing to do in pandas.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If this is efficient in pandas, can you please give an example and an explanation of how their algorithm works? I do not insist on using numpy. But I figured that pandas would be using numpy under the hood for operations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd put your arrays into a dataframe, then use `groupby` and the various methods of it: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})` 

mins = df.groupby('y').min()
```

Comment: In what format do `x` and `y` have to be to put them in the dataframe? I've tried the numpy arrays above and as lists.

Comment: Ah, you need quotations around the leading 'x' and 'y', right? So, `mins` is an object. It seems like the correct answer is under the `x` column of `mins`. How do I extract that column in particular?

Comment: In pandas you'd have simple access to the columns via, e.g., `mins.x` or `mins['x']`

Comment: Do you have a sense of what type of algorithm this is using behind the scenes? Could it be doing exactly what I am doing?

Comment: Pretty sure that's what it's doing behind the scenes :) Comes with all sorts of bells and whistles though

Comment: Thanks! I have been meaning to use pandas more. Maybe this is the nudge I need. I hope you'll understand if I leave the problem unsolved for a little longer. I am still interested to know if there are other algorithms which efficiently handle this task.